# ShEx Validation - reason and appInfo are null in Result Shape Map

Tags: java, validation, rdf, semantic-web, shex

I am learning ShEx and using 'shexjava API' done by http://shexjava.lille.inria.fr/ for my project. I have schema, data graph and fixed shape map. When I validate using refine and recursive validation, I am getting **ResultShapeMap** but the **reason** and **appInfo** are null for NONCONFORMANT status. I do not understand why these two fields are null.

I have schema, dataGraph, shapeMap. This is code for validation.

```
ValidationAlgorithm vl = new RefineValidation(schema, dataGraph); 
ResultShapeMap result = vl.validate(shapeMap);
```

Shape is,

```
{
  "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/shex.jsonld",
  "type": "Schema",
  "shapes": [
        {
          "id": "http://example.com/ns#HouseShape",
          "type": "Shape",      
           "expression": {
                "type": "EachOf",
                "expressions": [
                  { "type":      "TripleConstraint",
                    "predicate": "http://example.com/ns#number",
                    "valueExpr": { "type": "NodeConstraint", 
                                   "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#String"
                    }
                  },
                  { "type":      "TripleConstraint",
                    "predicate": "http://example.com/ns#size",                
                    "valueExpr": { "type": "NodeConstraint", 
                                   "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }      
        }
  ]
}
```

Data is,

```
ex:House1 a ex:House ; 
          ex:number "11A" ; 
          ex:size 23 .
```

My Result is,

```
ResultShapeMap [ 
   associations= [
      ShapeAssociation [
        nodeSelector=<example.com/ns#House>, 
        shapeSelector=<example.com/ns#HouseShape>, 
        status=NONCONFORMANT, 
        reason=null, 
        appInfo=null 
      ] 
   ] 
]
```

I want to output the reason for not conforming. But it gives me null for that.

Could some one please help me.

Comment: not sure what exactly you're asking, please provide code and data as well as the output and the expected result.

Comment: I have **schema, dataGraph, shapeMap**. This is code for validation. ValidationAlgorithm vl = new RefineValidation(schema, dataGraph); ResultShapeMap result = vl.validate(shapeMap);

Comment: This is my data =>

ex:House1 a ex:House ;
  ex:number "11A" ;
  ex:size 23 .

Comment: This is my Result is, 
ResultShapeMap [
 associations=
  [ShapeAssociation 
   [nodeSelector=<http://example.com/ns#House>, 
   shapeSelector=<http://example.com/ns#HouseShape>, 
   status=NONCONFORMANT, 
   reason=null, 
   appInfo=null
   ]
  ]
 ]
  
I want to putput the reason for not conforming. But it gives me null for that.

Comment: nah, edit your question ... nobody wants to read code in comments.

Comment: I've edited the question. do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shexjava implementation currently does not support indicating a reason for failure.
This is because when a node does not satisfy a shape there may be several reasons.

If you want to learn ShEx, I would advise you to use ShapeDesigner

https://gitlab.inria.fr/jdusart/shexjapp/

which provides a graphical interface in which you can explore validation results.

In this particular case, it indicates that the validation fails because 23 is not a decimal (it's actually an integer) [Screenshot of validation exploration result in ShapeDesigner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIErQ.png)

I do not know whether this is a bug, i.e. whether integrers should be considered to be also decimals in RDF.

Comment: As you are saying, shexjava API does not support giving the reason for failure. But ShapeDesigner is giving me the reason for failure in the column of message (but only gives only one reason for me). So how does it work? ShapeDesigner is using another library other than shexjava API? or how does it giving the reason?
Thank you

Comment: Shexjava API allows to listen to validation events, this is used by ShapeDesigner. The difficulty is that there is no such thing as _the_ reason for failure. (For a non matching triple, how can an algorithm know whether the predicate is misspelled or the data value is incorrect ?) So ShapeDesigner simply says which triples matched against which triple constraints, and which sub-expressions are not satisfied. It's up to you to figure out how to change your data to satisfy the schema.
That is, failure reasons are note part of ShEx standard and are implementation specific.